# Should there be a comma between 'you' and 'darling' here?

Tags: oxford-comma

Should there be a comma after you in the following sentence?

> Here's to you darling.

Comment: Something has come between us, darling. I fear it's a comma.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**. Introductory phrases are followed by a comma.

*"Here's looking at you, kid."* -Bogart